# WebService ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have created a WebMethod in a WebService that uses stored procedures to find whatever you are searching for.

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet getMyData(string search)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("searchingads", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", search);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds, "MyData");

        conn.Close();


        conn.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

I don't know how to call this method from an ASP.NET application. I have a button that, when clicked, needs to call this method and populate a GridView.

I have the following code in my ASP.NET web application (on button click):

```
WebService1 service = new WebService1();

GridView2.DataSource = service.getMyData(TextBox1.Text);
GridView2.DataBind();

Label1.Text = service.HelloWorld();
```

The label switches to "hello world" when the button is clicked, but it doesn't give me any table when I do a search.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Add service reference in your asp.net application and use the service via namespace addition or directly.

Comment: Is your stored procedure working fine and giving data.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

GridView2.DataSource = service.getMyData(TextBox1.Text);

instead of

GridView2.DataSource = service.IskanjeOglasov(TextBox1.Text);

Comment: Well its not that, it was just a type mistake, it still doesnt show any data

Comment: then pls use datatable from dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tested your search logic and its returning the data then try by assigning the data table as data source not the data set.

```
GridView2.DataSource = ((DataSet)service.getMyData(TextBox1.Text)).Tables[0];
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Here I have removed the check part of dataset. This might work.